# plotting sales and profit on one chart in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to make a profit vs sales chart in matplotlib, the profit line does appear on the chart but the sales line does not.
here is my code

```
plt.figure(figsize = (30,20))
plt.plot(data.groupby('State')['Sales'].agg([sum]).sort_values('sum',ascending = False))
plt.plot(data.groupby('State')['Profit'].agg([sum]).sort_values('sum',ascending = False))
```

This is how i am expecting the chart should look:

[image: 1]

This is how my chart looks:

[image: 2]

This is head of Profit data

```
               sum
State   
California  76381.3871
New York    74038.5486
Washington  33402.6517
Michigan    24463.1876
Virginia    18597.9504
```

This is head of Sales data

```
                sum
State   
California      457687.6315
New York        310876.2710
Texas           170188.0458
Washington      138641.2700
Pennsylvania    116511.9140
```

also how do i make y bar in millions ?

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot( data.groupby('State')['Sales'].agg([sum]).sort_values('sum',ascending = False), color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color) 
ax2.plot(data.groupby('State')['Profit'].agg([sum]).sort_values('sum',ascending = False) , color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Well you need to rotate the x-tick labels, but basically it's a `twinx` problem: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330427/set-y-axis-in-millions and check here for y-axis in millions

Comment: hey thank you for your reply but it still does not work  https://imgur.com/a/I6wK5Uu @ArtyomAkselrod

Comment: @Sayaji please provide code that you've used, it is hard to understand what does not work for you now

Comment: updated the code. @ArtyomAkselrod

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46652187/7758804) from the duplicate. Maybe others, but I only tried that one. `ax1.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=90)`.